# Recursively calling functions within functions in Python (trying to replicate MATLAB behaviour)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, recursion

In MATLAB this function (by Hao Zhang) calls itself

```
function r=rotmat2expmap(R)

% Software provided by Hao Zhang
% http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~nhz/software/rotations

r=quat2expmap(rotmat2quat(R));
```

as an argument to the function

```
function [r]=quat2expmap(q)

% Software provided by Hao Zhang
% http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~nhz/software/rotations
%
% function [r]=quat2expmap(q)
% convert quaternion q into exponential map r
% 
% denote the axis of rotation by unit vector r0, the angle by theta
% q is of the form (cos(theta/2), r0*sin(theta/2))
% r is of the form r0*theta

  if (abs(norm(q)-1)>1E-3)
    error('quat2expmap: input quaternion is not norm 1');
  end
  sinhalftheta=norm(q(2:4));
  coshalftheta=q(1);
  r0=q(2:4)/(norm(q(2:4))+eps);
  theta=2*atan2(sinhalftheta,coshalftheta);
  theta=mod(theta+2*pi,2*pi);
  %if (theta>pi), theta=2*pi-theta; r0=-r0; end
  if (theta>pi)
    theta=2*pi-theta; 
    r0=-r0; 
  end
  r=r0*theta;
```

Now if we pass a rotation matrix to the first function something along the lines of

```
R =

    0.9940    0.0773   -0.0773
   -0.0713    0.9945    0.0769
    0.0828   -0.0709    0.9940
```

It recursively calculates the correct result (in this case) simply:

```
r =

   -0.0741   -0.0803   -0.0745
```

Alas this is in MATLAB and it works fine (the original author knew what he was doing). I have not quite managed to get the same functionality to work in Python (I am effectively translating the code), I am going wrong somewhere:

```
def rotmat2expmap(R):
    """
    Convert rotation matrix to exponential mapping.
    Based on G.W. Taylor's MATLAB equivalent.
    """
    r = quat2expmap(rotmat2expmap(R))
    return r

def quat2expmap(q):
    """Converts quaternion q (rotation matrix) into exponential map r.
    Provided by Hao Zhang and G.W. Taylor.

    Denote the axis of rotation by unit vector r0, the angle by theta
    q is of the form (cos(theta/2), r0*sin(theta/2))
    r is of the form r0*theta
    """
    if abs(np.linalg.norm(q,2)-1) > 1e-3:
        print('quat2expmap: input quaternion is not norm 1')

    # Implement to simulate MATLAB like linear array structure
    temp = q.T.flatten()

    sinhalftheta = np.linalg.norm(temp[1:4],2)
    coshalftheta = temp[0]
    r0 = temp[1:4]/(np.linalg.norm(temp[1:4],2) + np.spacing(1))
    theta = 2*math.atan2(sinhalftheta,coshalftheta)
    theta = fmod(theta+2*pi,2*pi) # Remainder after division (modulo operation)
    if theta > pi:
        theta = 2*pi-theta
        r0 = -r0
    r = r0*theta

    return r
```

If I try to run this (with the same example R) then the number of loops maxes out and the whole thing crashes.

Anyone got any fancy ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have misread the original function definition. It doesn't recursively call itself, it calls instead `rotmat2quat` (not `rotmat2expmap`). You presumably need to implement `rotmat2quat` (see e.g., https://github.com/gwtaylor/imCRBM/blob/master/Motion/rotmat2quat.m ).

You are correct in how you are calling a function recursively in Python. However, *in any language* calling a function recursively without first applying some reduction (to make the input smaller) will result in an infinite recursion. This is what is happening in your Python code and why it is hitting a recursive depth limit. It is also what would happen in the MatLab code if it was written as you originally suspected. That is you have, essentially, f(R) -> f(R) -> f(R) -> f(R) -> f(R) -> ... . The input never changes before the recursive call, and so each time it makes another recursive call and never ends. Hopefully this is clear.

Comment: A case of not reading the code properly. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.